# How do I pass an operator to a scheme function

Tags: scheme, operators

I am having problems with a scheme function.

```
(define myfun(operator lis)
   (if(null? lis)
     '()
    (cons(operator (car lis)(car lis))myfun(operator (cdr lis))
))))
```

The function takes an operator as an parameter and a list for example `(+'(1 2 3 4))`
and the error i get when i try to call the function is : expecting a number but received a list. So my question is how do i call a function recursively with an operator and a list?

UPDATE: just needed a `'` sign before the operator.

Comment: There are no "operators" in Scheme. Rather, there are some functions whose names consist of symbols. They work just like any other functions, so you can call them, pass them just like you would any other function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just pass `+` to the function, without any quoting. `+` denotes the addition function.

```
(define (apply-op op x)
  (op x x))
```

will perform

```
(apply-op + 2)  ==>  4
```

Comment: Looking at your code, I can immediately predict that you're having parenthesis issues: specifically, you have left-parens right after identifiers, e.g. "cons(operator" . This is a huge warning sign that you're thinking of that left-paren as being part of the call to cons, and not the call to operator. Keep an eye out for this pattern in your code!